# ApplicationContextAware not working in Spring 3.0

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was trying out a simple example but it did not worked.

ApplicationContextHolder class implementing the Aware:

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextHolder implements ApplicationContextAware {

private static ApplicationContext context;

@Override
public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context)
        throws BeansException {
    this.context = context;
}

public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext(){
    return context;
}
}
```

**App.java**

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    ApplicationContext context = ApplicationContextHolder.getApplicationContext();
    // context in above line is coming as null
}
```

Below is the xml entry I have:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.XXX" />
```

Please let me know why is the `context` coming as null in the **App.jaa** class. Do I need to make some entry for class implementing the `Aware` somewhere int he xml file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to initialize `ApplicationContext` first

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
  ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");
  // 'spring.xml' has to add ApplicationContextHolder to its scan path

  ApplicationContext contextFromHolder =
    ApplicationContextHolder.getApplicationContext();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**ApplicationContetAware**  *Interface to be implemented by any object that wishes to be notified of the ApplicationContext that it runs in.*

In  your case there is none. You have to first bootstrap Spring as this is a standalone/console app, through java code.
 You have to first initialize the applicationcontext/BeanFactory.

Use  ApplicationContext (preferebly ClassPathXmlApplicationContext if your using xml configuration)

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(contextfile.xml);
```

**ApplicationContextHolder** will now have the reference of current ApplicationContext.

Answer (score 0):

Complete workable Example below:

**MyContext.java**

```
package jbr;

    import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextAware;

    public class MyContext implements ApplicationContextAware {

        private static ApplicationContext ctx;

        public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext context) throws BeansException {
            ctx = context;
        }

        public static ApplicationContext getCtx() {
            return ctx;
        }
    }
```

**Person.java**

```
package jbr;

public class Person {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getAge() {
        return age;
    }

    public void setAge(int age) {
        this.age = age;
    }

    private int age;
}
```

**conf.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="jbr" />

    <bean id="myCtx" class="jbr.MyContext" />
    <bean id="person" class="jbr.Person">
        <property name="name" value="Ranjith" />
        <property name="age" value="23" />
    </bean>

</beans>
```

**App.java**

```
package jbr;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("jbr/conf.xml");
        Person p = (Person) context.getBean("person");
        System.out.println(p.getName() + " > " + p.getAge());

        ApplicationContext ctx = MyContext.getCtx();
        Person p1 = (Person) ctx.getBean("person");
        System.out.println(p1.getName());
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
May 11, 2017 3:26:15 PM org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@37bba400: startup date [Thu May 11 15:26:14 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
May 11, 2017 3:26:15 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [jbr/conf.xml]
Ranjith > 23
Ranjith
```